# Swift: Multipeer Connectivity + UI Update

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, user-interface, multipeer-connectivity

My application is to communicate between about 5 iPads and update according to the data received through multipeer connectivity framework.

One of the iPad do the followings: It get its current location and send it to other peers. The peers update the UI according to the location received.

I found that there is a problem that when the iPad need to send the packet to the others, it cause its UI did not update immediately. The UI events stuck until it finished sending the packet. Since the location keep on updated, all these events fired continuously.

I have tried to place the send packet in a thread:

```
  let bgQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "hk.edu.polyu.isurf.sendqueue", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)
```

And then put the code for sending packet inside this bgQueue:

```
func sendPacket {
  bgQueue.async {
     // create packet, and send 
  }
}
```

My location update code will cause this:

```
func receiveLocation() {
   sendPacket()
   updateUI()
}
```

How can I improve the efficiency? The UI basically cannot update now, it is of serious "lagging".

I have tried to change the type of the bgQueue, but no improvement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your UI is being updated on the main queue.

If your trying to update UI in the session didRecieve function, this is a function that runs in the background. This means any UI changes made inside of it need to be put inside a Dispatch to the main queue so its updates take place immediately.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
// UI updates go here
}
```